# Placing Files in an Empty File Structure Based on a Separate List?

Tags: macos, automation, applescript

Is there a reasonably simple way to place files into a folder structure based on a list or spreadsheet?

Suppose, for example, I have 100 different images of animals; an empty folder structure of classifications - a Kingdom folder containing 5 different Family folders, each containing 5 Species folders; and a spreadsheet of each filename and its corresponding kingdom, family, and species. How might I write a bit of applescript, or tell automator, to interpret the information in the spreadsheet to move or copy each image the directory specified in the spreadsheet?

I've found plenty of good ways to place things in specific directories, but not much in using a separate list to specify the file's destination.

Thanks,
Al

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way is to save the Excel list into a text /tab delimiter file. Then the script can read that file.

In the script bellow, I assume the text file always have the 3 columns filename, family folder name and species folder name.

The script asks first the source folder (where all images are), then the 'kingdom' folder (where sub folders and images will be) and finally the text file (from Excel).

Then the script loops to every lines of the text file, and move the file to relevant folders. if the sub folders family or species do not exist, then script creates them before moving the image.
if the line of the text file does not contains 3 values, then line is skipped.

I put many comments to let you adjust if needed :

```
set Source to (choose folder with prompt "Select images folder") as text
set Kingdom to (choose folder with prompt "Select destination folder") as text

set Ftext to choose file with prompt "Select text file containing naes & folder paths"
-- file format must be : FileName <tab> FamilyFolder <tab> SpeciesFolder <return>

set FContent to read Ftext
set allLines to every paragraph of FContent
repeat with aline in allLines
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {ASCII character 9} -- use tab to split columns
set T to every text item of aline
if (count of text items of T) = 3 then -- valid line
    set FName to text item 1 of T
    set Family to text item 2 of T
    set Species to text item 3 of T
    tell application "Finder"
        try
            -- check if file Fname in Source folder exists
            if not (exists file (Source & FName)) then
                display alert "the file " & FName & " does not exist in source folder."
                return
            end if
            -- check if folder Family in Kingdom folder exists
            if not (exists folder Family in folder Kingdom) then
                make new folder in folder Kingdom with properties {name:Family}
            end if
            -- check if folder Species in Family folder exists
            if not (exists folder Family in folder Family of folder Kingdom) then
                make new folder in folder Family of folder Kingdom with properties {name:Species}
            end if
            -- then move FName from Source to Kingdom / Family / Species
            move file (Source & FName) to folder Species of folder Family of folder Kingdom
        end try
    end tell
end if
end repeat
```

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thanks so much for the solution.